# Spring Boot Task Scheduling - rerun a task conditionally

Tags: spring-boot, job-scheduling

I have an application where users can schedule to run reports at a certain time. The data for the reports is populated by an overnight batch process which might get delayed (occasionally) due to upstream issues. When that happens, the reports need to be re-tried every few minutes until we have data. I have a db table that records the status of the batch, there will be a row in that table when the data becomes available for this report. 
I am thinking along these lines: When the data is not available, the task will cancel itself, but before it does that, it will dynamically schedule another copy of itself to execute every 5 mins. Once the data becomes available, the repeating task will run once and cancel all future runs. 
Is this possible? Am I on the right track?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a bit of code: How does your task looks like at the moment. How is it being scheduled. Are you using @Scheduled or Spring Batch?

Comment: I have not written any code yet, I am brainstorming about the approach I should take at the moment. I will use which ever tool provides rerunning of jobs, @Scheduler, Spring batch or even Quartz library. Thanks.